# Python: Can "elif" ever be evaluated before "if"?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6, and am having difficulty understanding why the following code is throwing an IndexError at the location it is being thrown. The error occurs (incredibly rarely) when this version of the Porter Stemmer is incorporated into a web service.

The code involves a series of "if-elif-elif-else" statements which check an index of the input word for a series of scenarios. Note that self.k is an integer value (a placeholder) and self.ends(val) returns either a 0 or 1.

```
if self.b[self.k - 1] == 'a':
    if self.ends("al"): pass
    else: return
elif self.b[self.k - 1] == 'c':
    if self.ends("ance"): pass
    elif self.ends("ence"): pass
    else: return

...additional "elifs" appear here, but none modify self.b or self.k ...

elif self.b[self.k - 1] == 's':
    if self.ends("ism"): pass
    else: return
```

But, rarely (the input is highly variable), one of the "elif" statements throws an IndexError. For example:

```
line 290, in step4
elif self.b[self.k - 1] == 's':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What I cannot understand is why the evaluation of an "elif" is throwing an IndexError rather than the initial "if" statement? I do not yet have data on what input is throwing the error (again, the occurrence is very rare). It's also possible that the stemmer is receiving some type of "bad" input... Is there anything that I am missing/should be aware of with respect to Python if-elifs? (I am aware that an "elif" cannot precede "if"...).

Thanks, and let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Also, if you're interested in (most of) the full code, I'm using a modified version of this: http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/python.txt, but I don't think this is relevant to my question.

Comment: are you modifying self.b or self.k in any of these branches?

Comment: I smell a multi-threading race condition.

Comment: The direct answer to your question in the title is "No", so something else is going on here.

Comment: Why `if self.ends("al"): pass`/`else: return` where `if not self.ends("al"): return` will do?

Comment: An `if ... elif ... elif ...` sequence is a substitute for the switch or case statements found in other languages , so they are executed sequentially.

Comment: When you say "rarely", do you mean that it's not happening every time you run the program with the same input? Are you using multithreading? If you're not using threads, are you *sure* none of the intermediate steps are affecting either `self.k` or `self.b`? As others have noted, there is no way an `elif` will happen before an `if`

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% positive that you didn't screw up indentation anywhere (e.g., by mixing tabs and spaces) or turn one "elif" into an "if" when modifying PorterStemmer? Can you post your modified version?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The code the OP linked to doesn't do any threading (in fact, it doesn't import anything but sys). Of course he's using "a modified version", so it's certainly possible that he's added threading in somewhere…

Comment: @abarnert: From the OP: *"The error occurs (incredibly rarely) when this version of the Porter Stemmer is incorporated into a web service."*. Combined with the symptoms that tells me to go look for a threading problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: True. But either way, we need to see his modified version of the code. (Of course even if he isn't doing any threading in this module, or referencing any variables exposed outside of it, there could still be a race below the Python level—e.g., a thread running without the GIL—but it would remove much of the guesswork.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nobody else is modifying self.b or self.k, what's the point of checking it over and over again? Store it in a variable before the first if, and use it:

```
c = self.b[self.k - 1]
if c=='a': ...
elif c=='c': ...
```

Now, if someone else *is* modifying self.b or self.k in another thread, you should store it in a variable before your first if, and use it:

```
c = self.b[self.k - 1]
if c=='a': ...
elif c=='c': ...
```

Comment: Oh, and as others have already pointed out, something is most likely going on in another thread.